Analyzing Redistribution in Importance Sampling and Its Impact on Expected Values
Context: During reading "Importance Sampling" from Wikipedia, I saw this:

When X is of constant sign over Ω, the best variable L would clearly be $
L^{*} = \frac{X}{\mathbb{E}[X; P]} \geq 0
$, so that X/L* is the searched constant E[X;P] and a single sample under P(L*) suffices to give its value. Unfortunately we cannot take that choice, because E[X;P] is precisely the value we are looking for! However this theoretical best case L* gives us an insight into what importance sampling does:
$$
\forall a \in \mathbb{R}, \; P^{(L^{})}(X \in [a; a+da]) = \int_{\omega \in \{X \in [a; a+da]\}} \frac{X(\omega)}{\mathbb{E}[X; P]} \, dP(\omega) = \frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[X; P]} \, a \, P(X \in [a; a+da])
$$
to the right, $a \, P(X \in [a; a+da])$ is one of the infinitesimal elements that sum up to E[X;P]:
$$
\mathbb{E}[X; P] = \int_{a=-\infty}^{+\infty} a \, P(X \in [a; a+da])
$$
therefore, a good probability change P(L) in importance sampling will redistribute the law of X so that its samples' frequencies are sorted directly according to their weights in E[X;P]. Hence the name "importance sampling."

My question: It relates to the resulting distribution $P^{(L^*)}$. If we assume $X \sim N(1, 1)$, then according to $P^{(L^*)}$, we would have $P^{(L^*)}(X \in [0.25, 0.25+da]) < P^{(L^*)}(X \in [0.75, 0.75+da])$. Does this mean that $X \in [0.75, 0.75+da]$ contributes more to $\mathbb E[X,P]$ than $X \in [0.25, 0.25+da]$? This seems counterintuitive to me.
What exactly does “redistribute the law of X so that the sample frequencies are ordered directly according to their weights in $\mathbb E[X;P]$” mean?
